# Simple grading program returning the wrong answer

Tags: c++

Trying to write a simple program that takes six test grades, input by the user, drops the lowest, and then displays average of the remaining five. The program compiles fine, but outputs the wrong answer. Any pointers to where the logic error is occurring would be helpful. I am using these values as sample grades:
85.2
92.3
78.0
51.5
91.6
87.0
and the value returned should be 86.82, but the program is instead returning 80.08.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 6;
double grades[SIZE];
double low(double[]);

int main()
{
    double preavg = 0;
    double avg = 0;

    cout << "This program will take an input of six test grades\n"
         << "and determine the average of the highest five grades.\n\n"
         << "Please input the first test grade\n";
     cin >> grades[0];
    cout << "Please input the second test grade\n";
     cin >> grades[1];
    cout << "Please input the third test grade\n";
     cin >> grades[2];
    cout << "Please input the fourth test grade\n";
     cin >> grades[3];
    cout << "Please input the fifth test grade\n";
     cin >> grades[4];
    cout << "Please input the sixth test grade\n";
     cin >> grades[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        preavg += grades[i];
    }

    avg = (preavg - low(grades)) / (SIZE -1);

    cout << "Your average grade is " << avg << "\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

double low(double grades[SIZE])
{
    double lowest;

    lowest = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (grades[i] < lowest)
            lowest = grades[i];
    }

    return lowest;
}
```

Comment: Try printing out what is being calculated. Or run it with debugger and go step by step.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. this cpp.sh/5imp give me the correct answer

Comment: Oddly, to obtain 80.08 I have to change the first value 85.2 with another 51.5. Are you sure your input data are right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your issue here is possibly coming from the fact you're doing division in double precision using a `const int`. If you cast `SIZE` as a `double` and write the rest of your double numbers with a .0 on the end, it works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 6;
double grades[SIZE];
double low(double[]);

int main()
{
    double preavg = 0.0;
    double avg = 0.0;

    cout << "This program will take an input of six test grades\n"
         << "and determine the average of the highest five grades.\n\n"
         << "Please input the first test grade\n";
    cin >> grades[0];
    cout << "Please input the second test grade\n";
    cin >> grades[1];
    cout << "Please input the third test grade\n";
    cin >> grades[2];
    cout << "Please input the fourth test grade\n";
    cin >> grades[3];
    cout << "Please input the fifth test grade\n";
    cin >> grades[4];
    cout << "Please input the sixth test grade\n";
    cin >> grades[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        preavg += grades[i];
    }

    avg = (preavg - low(grades)) / ((double)SIZE - 1.0);

    cout << "Your average grade is " << avg << "\n";

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

double low(double grades[SIZE])
{
    double lowest;

    lowest = 100.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (grades[i] < lowest)
        lowest = grades[i];
    }

    return lowest;
}
```

Comment: `preavg` and the return value of `low()` are both `doubles`, so it should be `double` division.

Comment: Exactly what I thought... But making the changes I did makes it run successfully. I honestly have no idea why. Possibly to do with the const?

Comment: Thank you! I would have never figured that out, I'm using visual studio and changing the initial value of each double value to include a ".0" does make the program output the correct answer. Also, I did test my original code on cpp.sh without the ".0"s and it worked fine so I'm still not sure what Visual Studio is doing differently to cause the error.